# Sails JS : Blueprint API : Get Many to Many Relationship by ID is not working

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

Followed the documentation to create Users to Pets - Many to Many Relationship in Sails JS V10.5 - BluePrint API with MongoDB v2.6

Yet localhost:1337/user/54e38754b27f02212458e68e/pets?name=Pinkie%20Pie 
Finding the Owner's [Pet by Name](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1frEGpdapa2vndq5ibLCZcpeGjiX7tq-NJ41DzDVjSr8/edit#heading=h.cp4oiwjmv22j) works ..

{
    "name": "Pinkie Pie",
    "color": "pink",
    "createdAt": "2015-02-17T18:24:20.720Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-02-17T18:24:20.720Z",
    "id": "54e38754b27f02212458e691"
  }

But when the same pet is accessed via its ID 
localhost:1337/user/54e38754b27f02212458e68e/pets?id=54e38754b27f02212458e691 , the REST API [is not returning any value](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1frEGpdapa2vndq5ibLCZcpeGjiX7tq-NJ41DzDVjSr8/edit#heading=h.rvv2znfihuk).

Can you please let me know, how to enable additional logs to troubleshoot this basic Blueprint REST API access?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
GET /user/54e38754b27f02212458e68e/pets/54e38754b27f02212458e691
```

? The same applies also to POST and DELETE requests.

Comment: Hi Erk,   That is not workign .. Thats the concern.https://docs.google.com/document/d/1frEGpdapa2vndq5ibLCZcpeGjiX7tq-NJ41DzDVjSr8/edit#heading=h.rvv2znfihuk

Comment: I tried all the following yet it didn’t work. I mean No RESULT . 
http://localhost:1337/user/54e38754b27f02212458e68e/pets?id=54e38754b27f02212458e691
http://localhost:1337/user/54e38754b27f02212458e68e/pets/54e38754b27f02212458e691
http://localhost:1337/user/54e38754b27f02212458e68e/pets?pets.id=54e38754b27f02212458e691
 all 3 of them didn't work ..

Comment: The Source code is uploaded https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0fs0t6Bg6GGQ05SajJrMHpMYmc/view?usp=sharing To Test the same. If you have MongoDB, please create DBS - company1 ( as you can see in  connection.js ) . To Generate sample data between user & pets just enter http://localhost1337/user/hello. This function will load few users & pets and link them together. Then you will be able to access   localhost:1337/user/54e38754b27f02212458e68e/pets/54e38754b27f02212458e691 If this is not working then how do we enable the debugger for Blueprint to troubleshoot this issue. Please let me know.